# pop-up jsp java.lang.NumberFormatException: null

Tags: javascript, java, jsp

When I click update button, pop-up in jsp(for update) is opening up. Also I am sending good id(Urunler id) from my `main.jsp` to `update.jsp`. İt's working, but all time pop-up jsp comes with id from behind. For example I clicked 1. id in my `main.jsp` and it returns as `?id=1` its ok, but pop-up jsp is with null(sending formatException). After one more click let suppose we click 2. id then my pop-up jsp open up as `?id=1`. So id always come from back.

**My click code in main.jsp:**

```
<td> 
    <a onclick='popup()' href="managergosterim.jsp?id=<%=user.getUrunId()%>" >Güncelle</a> 
</td>
```

**pop-up jsp stuff in main.jsp :**

```
function popup(){ 
    window.open('update.jsp?<%=request.getQueryString()%>','name','width=500,height=500');
}
```

This is my main.jsp

```
<%@page import="entities.Urunler"%>
<%@page import="org.hibernate.Query"%>
<%@page import="org.hibernate.Session"%>
<%@page import="org.hibernate.SessionFactory"%>
<%@page import="entities.Uyeler"%>
<%@page import="org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationConfiguration"%>
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<title>MANAGER Ürünler</title>

</head>
<body>
    <divdisplay:block;>
                 <div id="index">
                    <img style="float: right; display:inline-block;  "   src="Manager.png"  alt="Manager" />
                </div>
                <div id="sidebar">
                    <form class="login"   action="logout.jsp" method="Post">           
                        <input type="submit"  style="float:right;  display:inline-block;        margin: 5px; margin-bottom: 0px;  "  class="submit" value=" Çıkış Yap "   />       
                    </form> <br><br>
                    <form class="login"   action="Raporlama" method="Post">           
                        <input type="submit"  style="float:right; margin: 5px; margin-bottom: 0px; display:inline-block;   " class="submit" value=" PDF Oluştur "   />
                    </form> <br><br>
                </div>
            </div> 
            <table border=1 style="float:top" ><tr><th>Marka</th><th>Model</th><th>Fiyat</th><th>Renk</th><th colspan="3">Seçenekler</th> </tr>
            <%
                //**HERE WE RETRIEVE MANAGER DATABASE TABLES.**
                    out.println("<title>MANAGER     Ürünler</title>");
                    HttpSession oturum = request.getSession();
                    AnnotationConfiguration configiki = new AnnotationConfiguration();
                    configiki.addAnnotatedClass(Uyeler.class);
                    SessionFactory factory = configiki.configure().buildSessionFactory();
                    Session sessioniki = factory.getCurrentSession();
                    sessioniki.beginTransaction();
                    Query queryResult = sessioniki.createQuery("from Urunler");
                    java.util.List allUsers;
                    allUsers = queryResult.list();
                    for (int i = 0; i < allUsers.size(); i++) {
                        Urunler user = (Urunler) allUsers.get(i);
            %>
                <tr>
                    <td><%=user.getMarka()%></td>
                    <td> <%=user.getModel()%></td>
                    <td><%=user.getPrice()%></td>
                    <td><%=user.getRenk()%></td>
                    <td> <a onclick='popup()' href="managergosterim.jsp?id=<%=user.getUrunId()%>" >Güncelle</a> </td>
                    <td> <a href="del.jsp?id=<%=user.getUrunId()%>">Sil</a> </td>
                </tr>
            <%
                }
                    //**EACH TABLE ROWS HAVE DELETE(href to DEL.Jsp) AND UPDATE(HREF TO GUNCELLE.JSP) .**
            %>
            </table>
            <script>
                function popup(){       
                    window.open('update.jsp?<%=request.getQueryString()%>','name','width=500,height=500');
                }
            </script>

      </body>
</html>
```

This is pop-up jsp.

```
<%@page import="org.hibernate.Query"%>
<%@page import="java.util.List"%>
<%@page import="org.hibernate.Session"%>
<%@page import="org.hibernate.SessionFactory"%>
<%@page import="entities.Urunler"%>
<%@page import="org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration"%>
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<title>JSP Page</title>
<style>
.mdl {
    font-size: 20px;
    font-family: serif;
    margin: 5px;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
    <h3>Ürünün yeni değerlerini giriniz</h3>
    <form>
        <%!void degistir() {
        HttpServletRequest request = null;
        String marka = request.getParameter("marka");
        String model = request.getParameter("model");
        String fiyat = request.getParameter("fiyat");
        String renk = request.getParameter("renk");
        Configuration confi = new Configuration();
        confi.addAnnotatedClass(Urunler.class);
        SessionFactory factor = confi.configure().buildSessionFactory();
        Session oturumiki = factor.getCurrentSession();
        oturumiki.beginTransaction();
        List allItem;
        Query queryResultz = oturumiki.createQuery("from Urunler");
        allItem = queryResultz.list();
        for (int i = 0; i < allItem.size(); i++) {
            Urunler urun = (Urunler) allItem.get(i);
            if (request.getParameter("id").equals(urun.getUrunId())) {
                urun.setMarka(marka);
                urun.setModel(model);
                urun.setPrice(Integer.parseInt(fiyat));
                urun.setRenk(renk);
            }
        }

    }%> <%
            int gelenid = Integer.valueOf(request.getParameter("id"));
            out.println("gelen id su : " + gelenid);
            Configuration configiki = new Configuration();
            configiki.addAnnotatedClass(Urunler.class);
            SessionFactory factory = configiki.configure().buildSessionFactory();
            Session sessioniki = factory.getCurrentSession();
            sessioniki.beginTransaction();
            List allItems;
            Query queryResult = sessioniki.createQuery("from Urunler");
            allItems = queryResult.list();
            for (int i = 0; i < allItems.size(); i++) {
                Urunler urun = (Urunler) allItems.get(i);
                if (gelenid == urun.getUrunId()) {
        %>

        Marka : <input type="label" class="mdl" name="marka"
            value="<%=urun.getMarka()%>" /><br> Model : <input type="label"
            class="mdl" name="model" value="<%=urun.getModel()%>" /><br>
        Fiyat : &nbsp;&nbsp;<input class="mdl" type="label" name="fiyat"
            value="<%=urun.getPrice()%>" /><br> Renk : &nbsp;&nbsp;<input
            type="label" class="mdl" name="renk" value="<%=urun.getRenk()%>" /> <br>
        <br> &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; <input
            type="submit" class=mdl value="Değiştir" onClick="degistir()" />


        <%
            }

            }
        %>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to understand what is the difference between client side and server side. Here is an explanation what really happens in your example scenario:

1. (Client) Go to `/main.jsp` (no query params)
2. (Server) Render `main.jsp`, but `request.getQueryString()` is empty, so rendered function popup will be:

   ```
   function popup(){       
       window.open('update.jsp?','name','width=500,height=500');
   }
   ```

   and send response (rendered html) to Client.
3. (Client) Click on record with `id=1` (but it doesn't matter what id it is, because every call of popup function is the same).
4. (Client) Go to `/update.jsp?`
5. (Server) Try to render `update.jsp`, but there was no query string so, `id` param is `null` (it cause exception).

**Possible solution:**

Change `popup` definition:

```
function popup(id){       
     window.open('update.jsp?id='+id,'name','width=500,height=500');
}
```

and change `popup` call

```
<td> 
     <a onclick='popup(<%=user.getUrunId()%>)' href="managergosterim.jsp?id=<%=user.getUrunId()%>" >Güncelle</a> 
</td>
```

Comment: Ty you very much.Very clear to understand.Appreciate it